# Getting started with a project

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, foundry

I'm new to smart contract and eth development but I have a project I'm planning to start and wanted to get a guide on the tools and framework I should be using.

I'm gonna be writing smart contracts in solidity, have a javascript frontend, and use Chainlink functions for an Oracle. I've used Remix in the past but I'm pretty sure that I should be using something like Foundry ideally to develop the smart contracts.

Anyone have any guidance or resources on my ideal setup for a project like this? Is there anything specific to using an Oracle that should make my setup different? Is there any good tool for testing interacting the frontend with smart contracts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with front-end, but you can use `hardhat` to develop, test, deploy, etc... with your smart-contract.

Unit-test can be written by javascript or typescript, so I think it will be easy for you.

You can check the docs here: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/getting-started

Beside it, you can check hardhat boilerplate project which includes frontend here: https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

For testing how the frontend corresponding to a contract's function call looks and to simulate how you'll be interacting with the contracts on a frontend, you can use something like:

1. [Thirdweb](https://thirdweb.com/): You can watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1LzOyynGT2U) regarding the same.
2. [Scaffold-ETH-2](https://github.com/scaffold-eth/scaffold-eth-2): You can watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShJZf5lsXiM) regarding the same.

Since you're using JavaScript for your frontend, for building custom UI components with a modular approach, you can use frameworks like [React.js](https://react.dev/) or [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) to build your user interface. These frameworks work well with web3 libraries like [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.org/) or [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/), which you'll use to interact with your smart contracts from the frontend.